# How to access Cassandra database in openshift

Tags: cassandra, openshift

Hawkler metrics data is stored in Cassandra database in openshift.

So, is all pods information stored in Cassandra?

And are CPU usage, memory usage and network usage of all pods running in cluster stored in Cassandra database?

How can I connect to this Cassandra database to get data?

Or how can I retrieve the data of any pods from Cassandra running?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. lease check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This first options is to run nodetool scrub. It attempts to rebuild the SSTable, and will throw away data that cannot recovered. This command requires Cassandra to be running.

The second option is to run sstablescrub which does not require the Cassandra instance to be up. It is basically an offline version of nodetool scrub. Any data that cannot be fixed will be ignored.